# yii query string do not change when click language picker

Tags: yii, url-rewriting, yii-url-manager

Actually My web having language picker, its working nice but some one give redirect url for my webapp.

Example

```
http://yii.mywebapp.com/?redirecturl=http://www.google.com
```

It's all working fine...

But when click language picker the url will be

```
http://yii.mywebapp.com/?language=en
```

But i need the url not fully changed, i need only the full url following way

```
http://yii.mywebapp.com/?redirectUtl=http://google.com&language=en
```

How can i do this one?

Comment: Show us some code, please.

Comment: Language Picker link

<a href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/?language=fr">French</a>

My Login  I set hidden field 

$redirect = $_GET['redirectUrl'];
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $redirect; ?>" name="redirectUrl" />

When i click language link it will be 

http://yii.mywebapp.com/?language=fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you simply want to preserve all GET parameters in the URL and simply add the language parameter to it.

The [Yii Request object](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getQueryString-detail) has a method called `getQueryString()` which will return all parameters currently available as a String.

Using that you could do the following to the example code you posted above to create your language picker URL:

```
<?php
$getParams = Yii::app()->request->getQueryString();
// ... 
?>
<!-- ... -->
<a href="<?php echo $baseURL . (empty($getParams) ? '?' : '&amp;' ); ?>language=fr">…</a>
```